# Matching two columns of different data frames

Tags: r, merge

How to match two columns of different data frame using R? Matched values should align at same position and missing values will be NAs.

Inputs:

```
df1$A: w x y 
df2$B: x y z
```

Expected output data frame:

```
w  x y NA
NA x y z
```

Comment: We can use `match`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'A', by.y = 'B', all = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Please read the info on [ask] and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a better way to represent this but right now I can figure this out. As mentioned in comments by @akrun, you can use `match`

```
unique(rbind(cbind(as.character(df1$A), as.character(df2$B[match(df1$A, df2$B)])), 
             cbind(as.character(df2$B), as.character(df1$A[match(df2$B, df1$A)]))))



#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "w"  NA  
#[2,] "x"  "x" 
#[3,] "y"  "y" 
#[4,] "z"  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this works fine...

`df1$B <- ifelse(df1$A %in% df2$B, as.character(df1$A), NA)`

`df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by='B',all.x = T,all.y = T)`

Comment: I think the ifelse is not needed, `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'A', by.y = 'B', all = TRUE)` will do just fine as far i can judge atm.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Well this just gives me (A: w x y z) as a single column dataframe output... Are you sure it works?

Comment: Depends on what the OP really wants (which is not clear atm)